# Como mostrar um jSon com jQuery e PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, json

Eu fiz esse ajax aqui, PS: os dados chegam até o arquivo dados.php

```
$.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          data: $( this ).serialize(),
          dataType: 'json',
          url:'simulacao/dados.php',
          success: function(data){
              alert(data);
            var objeto = data;
            $('#resposta').append(data.total_direta);;  
            }
        });
```

Porem, não consigo mostrar os valores na tela... O resultado do jSon é esse

```
{"total_direta":"21.450,00","total_indireta":"0,00","total_geral":"47.500,00"}
```

Minha duvida é, como eu mostro isso, existe uma div chamada id="resposta" mas ela não recebe nada...

Answer (score 0):

**Tente isso:**

```
$.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          data: $( this ).serialize(),
          dataType: 'json',
          url:'simulacao/dados.php',
          success: function(data){
              alert(data);
            // passa a resposta de string para JSON
            var resposta = JSON.parse(data);
            var objeto = data;
            $('#resposta').text(resposta.total_direta); 
            }
});
```

Eu simplesmente dei um JSON.parse() na resposta. Às vezes, a resposta é interpretada como string, então eu faço isso e funciona para mim.

Comment: Então, eu tentei mas não mostrou o resultado na tela, assim, como eu disse ele até vai a resposta, calcula, tudo... Mostra `{"total_direta":"21.450,00","total_indireta":"0,00","total_geral":"47.500,00"}` mas não retorna e imprime na tela... :/

Comment: Então, invés de fazer $('#resposta').append(), mude para $('#resposta').text();

Comment: Editei minha resposta para que fique claro.

Comment: é, não, também não imprimiu o resultado do json na tela...

Comment: Cara, seria bom que você colocasse o código inteiro aí então.
Ele dá o alert nos dados, mas não insere na #resposta? Estranho.

Comment: Tente tirando a linha do: dataType: 'json'

Comment: Então, na verdade nem o alert ele não da, mas o status da resposta é 200, então ele deveria cair no success... Mas bom, tirei o dataType: 'json',  e mesmo assim não foi, nem o print na tela... O Código de dados.php aqui

Comment: `/*Comissao direta*/ 
 $porcentagem  = '1.43%';
 $casas_vend  = $_POST['casa_vend'];
 $media_valor = $_POST['media_valor'];
 $total_direta  = (($media_valor  * $porcentagem) / 100) * $casas_vend ; 
 $data = array('total_direta'=> $total_direta,'total_indireta' => $total_indireta, 'total_geral' =>$total_geral);
 
 
 echo json_encode( $data );`

Comment: Os erros estão no php. Eu fiz aqui e retornou uma série de erros, dentre eles, o fato de que você está fazendo menção à variáveis inxistentes. 

E era pra você ter editado a resposta e colocado o código, não aqui nos comentários. Ficou muito confuso...

Comment: é que eu tirei o que de fato não interessava... Mas todas essas variaveis existem e eu as criei em um lugar... Vou botar no pastebin..

Comment: Consegui aqui, na verdade tinha 2 pontos... dataType que faltou, e tinha um método que nao existia chamado number_format no js, mas resolvi aqui \o

Answer (score 0):

Tente da seguinte forma

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    url:'simulacao/dados.php',
    success: function(data){
        $('#resposta').append(data[0].total_direta);
    }
});
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, esse código funcionaria, como eu expliquei no comentario da resposta acima, faltou o dataType e existia um método chamado number_format que não existe, eu, por algum motivo, pensei que existia um comando de formatação de numero nativo no js, mas muito bom, o seu código funcionaria perfeitamente!